# Run a command with relative path from symlink directory

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, symlink

I've got a directory structure like this:

```
bin
  drush
build -> vendor/drupal/core
vendor
  drupal
    core
```

So as you see, `build` is a symlink to the `core` directory.
`drush` is an executable file. I need to be able to `cd` into `build` and call `drush` from there.

But if I do this:

```
cd build
../bin/drush
```

This doesn't work, because `..` points to `vendor/drupal` directory, because when I `cd` into `build`, it in fact goes to `vendor/drupal/core`, of course.

I know I can call it this way: `../../../bin/drush`, but is there some kind of workaround to make `..` point to the root, not the actual parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an another symlink in the folder "drupal" on the executable drush. So with this way, you can call it from "build".

```
$ cd vendor/drupal/
$ ln -s absolute_path/bin/drush dummy-drush 
$ cd build 
$ ./dummy-drush
```

Solution 1 :
If you don't want to create anything in vendor, maybe it's better to create an alias which allows to you to execute drush (be careful to give the good path).

Solution 2 :

If the directory bin in your example is not the folder "/bin" from the root, you can add it in your PATH in order to execute every executable .

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/personal_bin/
$ cd bin
$ ln -s drush dummy-drush
```

Comment: That would work, but I don't wanna create anything into the `vendor` dir.

Comment: This is a local `bin` directory. And all of this is a group repo, there are several people working on it, including myself. So I want to make `drush` executable from `build` without extending $PATH, etc.

Comment: In this case, you should edit you .bashrc file with creating an alias giving the absolute path of drush and it's allow to you to execute drush from build.

Comment: But I want everyone who clones the repo to be able to do it. `.bashrc` would fix it for my machine only.